# AWS S3 not returning specified number of records

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

I'm reading the file from S3 bucket by specifying the range. But it is not giving me a specified length of data and always giving me lesser data. It might be due to S3 ignoring/skipping a few of the characters while reading which I'm not able to understand why.

```
  val stringBuilder = new StringBuilder

  val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion("us-east-1").withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider).build
  val rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest("test_bucket", "test_key")
    .withRange(0, 25738)

  val s3object = s3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest)

  System.out.println(s3object.getObjectMetadata.getContentType)
  System.out.println("content length: " + s3object.getObjectMetadata.getContentLength)

  val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3object.getObjectContent))
  var line = ""

  while ({line = reader.readLine; line != null}) {
    System.out.println(line + "  \nLength: " + line.length)
    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n")
  }

**Output:
binary/octet-stream
content length: 25739
< 3/4 of line read from the file printed here.>
Length: 25341**
```

How can I read the specified number of bytes from the file? If I read the file without specifying the range, the entire line is printed without any issue.

Comment: You're not printing the whole data you receive, you're only printing up to the first newline. What's the length inside `stringBuilder` after the `while` loop finishes?

Comment: It is the same value as the first line length. For testing, I had put only one line in the file so I'm printing the length of the first line only.

Comment: I found one more thing that, the length 25738 is considered as byte length (which I was thinking like a character length). And it is returning those many bytes.

Comment: Comparing char and byte doesn't really make sense

Comment: yeah. I know. I was just trying to understand how it works and trying many things. Ignore my previous comment.